# arp across different subnets

Tags: unix, networking, network-programming, tcp

how can a host find the mac address of system in another subnet.

Answer (score 2):

It, in general, can't. At least not without the host cooperating by e.g. sending it explicitly (as payload) using e.g. TCP or UDP. MAC addresses are only of interest to hosts on the same network, in general.

Comment: How about same physical net but different subnet?